# What does this TRIGGER do?

Tags: oracle, trigger, db2

I have this trigger in DB2 that I need to convert to ORACLE, but I don't know how it works in  DB2 so i can translate it to a ORACLE one, I think it doesn't do anything.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ERRLOG_TRIGGER
  NO CASCADE BEFORE INSERT
  ON ERROR_LOG
  REFERENCING 
    NEW AS NEWROW
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN ATOMIC 
     SET NEWROW."ERRLOG_CREATEDON" = CURRENT TIMESTAMP;
END;
```

I see that date update, but what is it for?

Comment: I figured out that ERROR_LOG is a table on my own schema not a systemtable of DB2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigger *does* something, it sets the `ERRLOG_CREATEDON` column to the current time.

In Oracle this should roughly be:

```
create or replace trigger errlog_trigger
  before insert on error_log
  for each row
begin
  :new.errlog_createdon := current_timestamp;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you, I should managed it by my own, I didn't see the clauses in DB2.